# Translating cURL command to PHP

Tags: php, curl, box-api

I'm trying to translate the following cURL command to PHP.

`curl -k https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content -H "Authorization: Bearer 8tuuIMsrf3ShyODVdw" -F filename=@txt.txt -F folder_id=0`

Here is my attempt:

```
$url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/content';
$params['filename'] = '@txt.txt';
$params['folder_id'] = '0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer ".$this->access_token, "Content-Type: multipart/form"));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It's not working however. Can anyone help me understand why what I'm doing is wrong and what I can do to modify my code?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting rid of the header `"Content-Type: multipart/form"` from your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option as cURL will take care of this for you based on your post data.

Since you are uploading a file, the content-type will automatically be set to `multipart/form-data` which is actually the correct content type, not `multipart/form`.

Comment: I tried doing this but I'm still running into problems.  One thing I'm not sure of is how to translate the -F cURL command to PHP.  From the cURL documentation, -F `lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388`. I wasn't really sure how to interpret this, so I just tried using them as params(key,value) in my POST request. Is this correct?

Comment: The -F is equivalent to your $params array and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option.  What is `$data`?  An error message or empty?

Comment: $data is empty. when I track the network activity, it says the POST request was sent without an error but nothing happens

Comment: Try `echo curl_error($ch);` after `curl_exec()` to see if there was an error.  In addition, `curl_getinfo()` can be useful to get info about the request and response.  What is this api call supposed to do? upload a file?

Comment: Also setting the option `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true is helpful as the response will include the http headers which may be useful when debugging erroneous responses from their API.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I'm away from the computer for the rest of the day but I will definitely try these things.  Great advice, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`curl -k` means insecure. Add the following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Translated from the german manual (Note that the english version is missing this information):

> If CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER has been deactivated, the option CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST has to be disabled as well.

The rest of your code should work fine.

Comment: Good catch, but I tried implementing this and my code still doesn't work. I think I have a fundamental problem with the code I have written, either with the way I'm setting the header, or translating the cURL -F command to PHP.  See my comment on the other answer for a little more detail.